# How to get window close event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal, session-cookies

How can I get close event of window? Tried onbeforeunload. But it is triggering for refresh too. How can I detect refresh and execute my script only in window close. Or is there any solution on server side to detect browser window close. I am using php

Comment: I don't believe you can differentiate between close and refresh.

Comment: ^^ That, and there is definitely no way to detect a browser event on the server, unless the browser *tells* the server.

Comment: You can use a trick like a ping send by your JS to the server each X seconds, save this time, and with something like a cron, check if (time_save + X seconds < time()).